# Malfunctioning semaphore

Tags: c, semaphore, mkfifo

I am trying to organize the interaction of two processes. The first process sends in the second 2 numbers. The second finds the amount and passes it to the first process. I use a named semaphore to synchronize these processes. After creating MKFIFO, I block this process so that it does not open it ahead of time. The second process at this time opens the previously created channel and writes the result to it, then releases the first process. But it turns out that the second process does not see the channel that created the first process for it. What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

test.c:

```
#define SEMAPHORE_NAME "/my_named_semaphore"

sem_t *sem;
int f1,f2;
double summ = 0;
unlink("mk.fifo");

if (mkfifo("mk.fifo", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH) == -1 && errno != EEXIST)
    error(0, errno, "mkfifo() error");

f1 = open("mk.fifo", O_WRONLY);
perror("Opening ");

write(f1, &a, sizeof(double));
write(f1, &b, sizeof(double));
perror("Writing ");

close(f1);

unlink("mk.fifoSumm");
if (mkfifo("mk.fifoSumm", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH) == -1 && errno != EEXIST)
    error(0, errno, "mkfifo() error");

    sem = sem_open(SEMAPHORE_NAME, O_CREAT, 0777, 0);
    printf("зашли в семафор\n");
    printf("ждем\n");
    sem_wait(sem);
    printf("подождали\n");
    f2 = open("mk.fifoSumm", O_RDONLY);
    perror("Opening ");

    read(f2, &summ, sizeof(double));
    perror("Reading ");

    close(f2);

printf("Received string '%lf'\n", summ);

return summ;
}
```

test2.c:

```
#define SEMAPHORE_NAME "/my_named_semaphore"

sem_t *sem;
int f2,f1;
double a = 0;
double b = 0;
double summ = 0;

f2 = open("mk.fifo", O_RDONLY);
perror("Opening ");

read(f2, &a, sizeof(double));
read(f2, &b, sizeof(double));
perror("Reading ");

close(f2);

printf("Received string '%lf'\n", a);
printf("Received string '%lf'\n", b);

summ = a + b;

sem = sem_open(SEMAPHORE_NAME, 0);
f1 = open("mk.fifoSumm", O_WRONLY);
perror("Opening ");

write(f1, &summ, sizeof(double));
perror("Writing ");

sem_post(sem);
printf("освободили семафор\n");

close(f1);
```

Comment: Looks like a timing issue based on the errors. Writes to a fifo are blocked until something is connected to on the other end so test2 is basically trying to open a fifo before it has been created (because test2 tries to open the fifo to write the result before test gets to creating the fifo).

Have you tried making the both mkfifo calls the first thing that happens in test.c?

See the docs here https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question